# Keyboard input stuttering and freezing

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting

Last time I've noticed a problem that sometimes my keyboard input is stuttering and freezing for a few seconds; does this mean I have some keyboard hook buggy or gone rogue, or there can be another reasons? How can I check keyboard hooks installed in my system?

PS I have MS Security Essentials installed and checking periodically.

UPD it seems this happens when any of CPU cores is utilized up to 100% by any program. Any ideas?

UPD2 I have i5-3550 CPU, 16GB RAM, SSD for the system disk.

UPD3 after some more experiments - this problem is not bound to CPU usage. It happens even when total CPU usage is less than 10%.

Comment: Does the system catch up and the key presses made during the "freeze" appear later? Does anything else about the system "freeze" at other times? Is this in any particular app?

Comment: 1. sometimes 2. it seems switching apps doesn't work in this time as well 3. in all apps

Comment: Can you test with another keyboard or OS, even one run from a LiveCD/USB?

Comment: I haven't noticed such a problem on Ubuntu running from LiveCD.

Comment: It most likely means that some background task is tying up the CPU and interrupt system.  Could be some sort of malware, but more likely to be, eg, Windows indexing or a virus scan or some other "maintenance" operation.  Can even be your browser just handling an "ugly" page.  Can be hard to track down at times.

Comment: (I had a problem with this box that, if I turned off the WiFi radio, interrupt servicing would drive one core to 100%.  There are many other potential pitfalls in a "modern" Windoze box.)  (Why do you think they call it "Windoze"?)

Comment: "it seems this happens when any of CPU cores is utilized up to 100%" -- You should find out which programs are doing this.  Install Microsoft Process Explorer for starters.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, this doesn't matter. Some of my programs are supposed to use as much CPU time as possible. However, it's not normal this makes keyboard input freeze.

Comment: It does matter (and it *is* "normal" for Windows).  Some programs are well-behaved, but others tie up the interrupts, etc, and can lock up the KB for several minutes at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my case was a defective keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Often an io-bound system can be a problem that manifests as high CPU simply because processing is blocked, this *something* is easily using 100% of the few cycles available. You can upgrade to an SSD, a faster spindle-based drive, or simply determine what's using high disk IO by going into system monitor.

Comment: I already have SSD.